# Vim Split :Sexplore - Flipping Splits

Tags: vim, split

Is there a way to define the default behavior of `:Sexplore` opening a new split below the current, rather than making it the top most?

Currently I have to do a `C-w J` to swap the splits each time I open a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:set splitbelow`. This will affect all splits however.

`:h 'splitbelow'` to read more.

Answer (score 1):

One of these solutions:

- `:set splitbelow`
- `:Hexplore`
- `:Sexplore | wincmd J`